# Java replaceAll with parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

In the code below I'm trying to replace in `text` occurrences of `fromString` with`toString`, but no replacement takes place. How to set the parenthesis in the regex to make this work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fromString = "aaa(bbb)";
    String toString = "X";
    String text = "aaa(bbb) aaa(bbb)";
    String resultString = text.replaceAll(fromString, toString);
    System.out.println(resultString);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replaceAll` uses regex as its first argument. Parenthesis `()` are used for [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) so need to be escaped

```
String fromString = "aaa\\(bbb\\)";
```

Since [you can't modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931025/java-replaceall-with-parenthesis#comment47984558_29931038) the input String you can use `Pattern.quote`

```
String resultString = text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(fromString), toString);
```

or simply `String.replace` could be used which doesnt use regex arguments

```
String resultString = text.replace(fromString, toString);
```

Comment: Agree: http://goo.gl/7p3N09

Comment: my issue is that I read `fromString` from a database and the parenthesis are already embedded in the field, how to escape the parenthesis?

Comment: You could use `Pattern.quote` but the simplest approach seems to be to use `String.replace`